# find records with lower case names and upper first letter names

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle db and in my tables some record names are all lower case and some have upper case in the first letter. example: Logan and logan. I need to be able to return both results.

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT uzer.email, uzer.firstname, uzer.lastname,  account.name, 
account.brand,account.id
FROM UZER, ACCOUNT, UZERACCOUNT
where UZER.ID=UZERACCOUNT.UZERID AND ACCOUNT.ID=UZERACCOUNT.ACCOUNTID
AND UZER.firstname='Logan'
```

Is there a way to do this without throwing in an OR? Because this query is going to grow to use last names too, and i need it to be fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using UPPER():

```
SELECT DISTINCT uzer.email, uzer.firstname, uzer.lastname,  account.name, 
account.brand,account.id
FROM UZER, ACCOUNT, UZERACCOUNT
where UZER.ID=UZERACCOUNT.UZERID AND ACCOUNT.ID=UZERACCOUNT.ACCOUNTID
AND upper(UZER.firstname)=upper('Logan' )
```

Comment: This works good. Thanks!